# Get Lines and corresponding coordinates from Google Vision API OCR

Tags: python, google-cloud-vision

Iam currently using google OCR Api. I can get coordinate points for every block.

My question is how to get coordinate points for every line.

The below link describes how to extract lines from paragraph.

[Get Lines and Paragraphs, not symbols from Google Vision API OCR on PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972479/get-lines-and-paragraphs-not-symbols-from-google-vision-api-ocr-on-pdf/52086299)

Answer (score -1):

Are you asking how to get the bounding boxes for each line you get from your linked StackOverflow question?

If so, I'd suggest you save the top- and bottom-left coordinates of the first word in each line and the top- and bottom-right coordinates of the last word in each line. This tuple then represents the box for every line in your file.