# Extracting receipt data line by line in a certain format

Tags: google-cloud-vision

[image]

How do I extract text from a receipt line by line with Google Vision?

I have tried matching with the Y coordinates but the result are not that ideal.

Is there other alternative to the approach?

Comment: How about ? -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51972479/get-lines-and-paragraphs-not-symbols-from-google-vision-api-ocr-on-pdf/52086299

Comment: @Inga890 Hi it didn't work, they close enough approach was using Y coordinates

Answer (score 0):

You should use `DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION` in the JSON request and in the `fullTextAnnotation` you will have `\n`

If you consider open sources, this git may be useful for line segmentation ,
[line-segmentation-algorithm-to-gcp-vision](https://github.com/sshniro/line-segmentation-algorithm-to-gcp-vision)